# Is there a possibility to hide the "buy" link in the Soundcloud HTML 5widget?

Tags: soundcloud

We'd like to embed Soundcloud in articles about artists using Soundcloud. But since we are a public radio station - we are not allowed to link to online stores. Is there any parameter that hides the "buy" link in the HTML 5 widget?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use `buying=false` GET parameter when inserting widget. You can see all possible parameters for the widget [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#params).